# define per connection variables for sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

How can I achieve something like following

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("CNStr");

SqlCommand Command = connection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "DECLARE @find varchar(30) = 'Test'; ";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "select * from Some_View_Which_Has_Used_That_Variable_In_ItsWhere_Condition"

var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.Dispose();

connection.Dispose();
```

I want to declare some per connection variable, and then use them everywhere, in views, functions and so on.

How can I achieve this goal without using temp table and contextId ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want something that can be parameterized, you're not looking for a view, you're looking for a function.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My problem is not as easy as your what you think, please read the question again, I want to have some per connection variables, to use them everywhere.

Comment: I have read your question. I've even provided an answer. Just because you want feature X to support option Y doesn't mean that the product that includes feature X does support option Y. View's cannot contain references to any variables or parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've used the context info as a dictionary of key value, and it's working fine, and as I told in my question, I'm aware of temp tables, I want to know is there any solution or not, and my sample code is to demonstrate my problem more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `DECLARE` in your sql statement.

It is not even valid [Data Manipulation Language statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766.aspx). It doesn't even effect your `Some_View_Which_Has_Used_That_Variable_In_ItsWhere_Condition` at all.

That's why it looks pointless to me. If you really want to declare `@find`, you can write in your view as manual.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

For example;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CNStr))
using(SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
{
  //
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wrote that sample to demonstrate my problem more clear. So is there any solution rather than context Info or temp tables ?

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious per-connection object that persists for longer than a single batch (i.e. your `ExecuteXXX` calls) would be a temp table:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #Settings (find varchar(30) not null);
                       INSERT INTO #Settings (find) VALUES ('Test')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "select * from Some_View where
                         SomeColumn in (select find from #Settings)"
var result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

All variables (whether scalar or table-valued) have lifetimes that end at the end of their respective batches.

A few other things can be set at the connection/session level (e.g. [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx)) but they tend to have fixed, limited data types.

Comment: You can define context info as varBinary and develop a clr stored procedure to write to that, and develop a clr scalar function to read from that ( as like as hash tables and dictionaries ), so it's not limited.

Comment: @YasserMoradi it can contain a maximum of 128 bytes. I'd call that a limit.

Comment: Yes, It's not designed for huge amount of data usage purposes, but is really enough for per connection information such as userId, roles Ids and a few other things. I'm using that fine, but I've developed several outer apply which are using my clr function of context info in lots of my queries, and Sql server is not going to invoke my clr function for necessary records as like as what oracle does provide. and I've performance trouble now )-:, I'm looking for a new way to provide some per connection variables, without performance side effect, and without changing all my triggers and view to sp.